# Knockout nested viewmodel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mvvm, knockout.js

I have a viewmodel setup that is as follows:

```
<div id='stuff'>

<div id='i_need_this'>
<input type='checkbox' data-bind="checked: enabled" />
</div>

</div>

<script>
var vm = new vm();
ko.applyBindings(vm, $("#stuff").get(0));
var i_need_this_vm = new i_n_t();
ko.applyBindings(i_need_this_vm, $("#i_need_this").get(0));
</script>
```

I have one viewmodel that is bound to the parent div of "stuff" but I want the i_need_this viewmodel to be bound to the i_need_this div. When I apply this binding though I am getting an error that "Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: enabled is not defined;" Is this related to how my viewmodels are arranged, and if so is there a way around it?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason that you can't have one view model inside of another as a dependency? I've structured view models a few layers deep to get past the issue you're having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can not bind a parent and child element to different viewmodels like that.  See this link for a possible work-around. http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html